# Hibernate Transaction Management in non-web application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I have a project that have a spring web application and a  multithreaded background application.

that this 2 projects have a one core consist of models classes and dao's.
in spring web application i using SessionInViewPattern that not need to open transaction and commit in my dao's class and in my background application that i can't use SessionInViewPattern i must open transaction and commit them.

because my dao classes is shared between 2 projects what is solution ?

Comment: Your DAOs should never deal with transactions. Transactions should be demarcated at the service layer.

Comment: I dont need @transactional because using OpenSessionInView pattern

Comment: My problem is my dao is shared between 2 project that in web project i dont need begin and comment transaction and in background project i must be begin and commit transaction.

Comment: No, you don't. Because DAO should not start and commit transactions. Services calling the DAOs should do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of implementing AOP(Aspect oriented programming) in your background project by wrapping your method which calls the DAO with the hibernate transaction. If your background project uses spring then its very easy to configure the hibernate transaction as an aspect.